# AWS EC2: Why can I access FTP from local address only?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ftp, amazon-vpc

I have installed vsftpd on a Ubuntu server on AWS however I can not access it via its Elastic IP.  If I ssh to the server, I can then ftp to it using its internal IP, but I can't ftp using its public IP.  What am I doing wrong?

As far as I can recall, the only change I made to `vsftp.conf` was to uncomment `local_enable=YES`.

The FTP server is in a VPC.  The default network ACL's are in place, and I have opened up TCP ports 20-22 to traffic from anywhere.

When I run `ftp 13.my.ip.address` it simply says the connection timed out.

Comment: Can you ping your server from an external PC? Check your internet gateway, routing table, security groups, network ACL. If all that is ok then it's likely application configuration. You can of course use the sftp server built into ssh, with local users in the instance. Don't forget backups.

Comment: I can't ping, but I can browse a web site on the server, so obviously it is reachable.

Comment: That suggests the problem is with the ftp server software, the security group, or the instance firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check below:

1. Port 20 and 21 are open at security group.
2. Above ports should be opened in iptables inside of host.
3. Check which address ftp is listening.
4. Is it enabled in any wrapper file(host allow/deny or userlist_file in conf) some config parameters are below.

   userlist_deny=NO

   userlist_enable=YES

   userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.allowed_users

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default security group only has 22, 80 and 443 open, so you will need to open 21 if you haven't already.

Comment: I have opened the ports on the security group...

Comment: Try `nmap $public_ip` to see if the port is open and something's listening.

Comment: nmap says port 20 is filtered ftp-data, and 21 is filtered ftp